# Checking if user input is a floating number

Tags: javascript

```
choice = input.questionFloat('\t1. Display all members\' information \n\t2. Display member information \n\t3. Add new member \n\t4. Update points earned \n\t5. Statistics\n\t6. Exit \n\t>> ');
if (choice.toString().includes('.')) {
   console.log ('Please enter a valid input.');
}
```

choice contains the input from the user. If choice is a floating number, it will prompt the user that it is a invalid input. If there a better way of doing this instead of using .includes?

Comment: `if (choice !== Math.floor(choice))`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I check that a number is float or integer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3885817/how-do-i-check-that-a-number-is-float-or-integer)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that easily with JavaScript.
First take and convert to number and check if it's truthy value (non NaN) and check if it's not integer.

```js
const num = Number('123.3')
if (num && !Number.isInteger(num)){
    //float
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not compare it to its value in int?

```
const intValue = 12
console.log(parseInt(value) !== value) // false => is an int

const floatValue = 12.1
console.log(parseInt(value) !== value) // true => is not an int
```