# Type check between integer and float type

Tags: javascript, node.js

what is maximum precision check we do for float and integer ?

```
 0 === 0.00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001 

true // output
```

Answer (score 1):

Looking at:

```
> Number.MIN_VALUE
< 5e-324
```

Versus:

```
> '0.000--etc--0001'.length
< 487
```

We can see that your number is smaller than the allowable minimum non-zero float, so it gets rounded down to zero, making the expression effectively:

```
> 0 === 0.0
< true
```

Comment: It's not that simple: `(1 + Number.MIN_VALUE) === 1` evaluates to `true`

Answer (score 0):

Javascript, Typescript has the only type of `Number`. By default, you can not declare float type. But you check the float value. I think you have the answer here. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3885817/how-do-i-check-that-a-number-is-float-or-integer)