# how do I retain the the zero at the end when I divide a number like 12330 by 100 in Javascript

Tags: javascript

how do I divide `12330 by 100` to give me `123.30`

trying 12330/100 in JS gives `123.3` but I want the 0 at the end to stay

also, I need the function to not give .00

so 100/100 should give `1` and not `1.00`

tried using `.toFixed(2)`. but it only solved the first case and not the second.

Comment: as a number, `123.30` is simply the same as `123.3` and JS will always display the simpler version. You want the *string* `"123.30"`, in which case use the `toFixed` method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `toFixed` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed

```js
console.log(
  (12330 / 100).toFixed(2)
);
```

> here `2` means, the precision of float

---

**Attention:** also when the number isn't a float it will do `number.00` *(in the most of cases this is good behavior)*

but if isn't good for you, see the next edited answer...

---

### new edited answer

if the `.00` gives you problems, use this:

> `%` operator, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Remainder

```js
function convert(value) {
  if (value % 1 === 0) {
    return value;
  }

  return value.toFixed(2);
}

// tests


console.log(convert(12330 / 100)); // should return value with toFixed

console.log(convert(100 / 100)); // should return 1 (no toFixed)

console.log(convert(100 / 10)); // should return 10 (no toFixed)
```

> for understanding more about this checking `(value % 1 === 0)` you can see this StackOverflow question on this topic [How do I check that a number is float or integer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3885817/how-do-i-check-that-a-number-is-float-or-integer)

Comment: Thanks, the issue is I don't want .00
using toFixed(2) on a perfect fraction like (100 / 100).toFixed(2) will give 1.00

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways you could do this. @Laaouatni's answer is one example (and if you go with that one, make sure to mark that as the answer).

I'll give two others here.

Using `string.prototype.slice`:

```js
const intermediate = value.toFixed(2);
const result = intermediate.endsWith(".00") ? intermediate.slice(0, -1) : intermediate;
```

Using `string.prototype.replace`:

```js
const result = value.toFixed(2).replace(".00", ".0");
```